# HOW TO USE LIST TEMPLATE IN OFFICE 365?

Tags: office365

how to copy a list from SharePoint 2013 into office 365 SharePoint steps please?

I have saved a list as template in SharePoint 2013 but not able to see in office 365 .May I know why?

Answer (score 1):

You will not find Link "List templates" on site setting page.
You need to paste the following link to address bar with site URL.
"_catalogs/lt/Forms/AllItems.aspx"

For example https://XXXXXXXX/_catalogs/lt/Forms/AllItems.aspx

It will open list template gallary.upload .stp here...
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Akshay.I have one more questions related to workflow .Is there any feasibility to update the list without affecting the approval workflow?